# Creating a search function in c#, windows form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

I am creating a program as part of a college assignment and must have a database connected to my program. The program is in c# and created in a windows form application with visual studio.
I need to have a text box that allows entry and then a button to search for any values that match that, but I cannot figure out how to read what is inputted, search the database and return them in the text boxes.
I already have the database connected and all of the forms designed and connected together with buttons, however this one part is really baffling me. Any help would be appreciated.P.S I am new to c# and do not fully understand it yet.

Comment: You should be able to pull the value from your textbox on the button click event.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Lewis Find my answer i have put the links where whole solutions is there

Answer (score 0):

Please Take Reference from this link your Answer(along with Database Queries) and Explanation is available

[Reference 1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-using-entity-framework-in-windows-form-application/)

[Reference 2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/insert-update-and-delete-record-in-datagridview-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, my tutor said that I was making things too complicated for myself and only needed to create a simple program, so I used the data set and linked the textboxes to that so that all information is displayed instead of searching and certain information being shown.
Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

1) Put all the texts from the database in some kind of collection (List for example).

2) Get the text from the textbox by accessing the textbox's Text property. Apply some modifications if you want, such as removing caps, handling keywords etc.

3) Write a linq query that goes something like collection.Where(t => t.Contains(searchString)).ToList(). Alternatively, you can loop over the collection.

4) Feed the resulting list to your output textbox.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my tutor said that I was making things too complicated for myself and only needed to create a simple program, so I used the data set and linked the textboxes to that so that all information is displayed instead of searching and certain information being shown.
Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was used a dataGridView for the `DataSet` of mysql data and below is the sample code for searchbox.

```
private void tfSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tfSearch.Text) == false)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                for(int i = 0; i < GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string id = GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    string name = GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    string price = GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    string stock = GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    if (name.StartsWith(tfSearch.Text))
                    {
                        int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = id;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = name;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = price;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = stock;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(tfSearch.Text == "")
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string id = GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    string name = GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    string price = GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    string stock = GlobalState.Items.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();

                    int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = id;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = name;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = price;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = stock;

                    
                }
            }
```

Your Welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Get the textbox text when you click on the button then start a query with that search word so youll get back everything what contains that word

Get input text

```
Textboxname.text;
```

Query

```
SELECT * ON table WHERE tagoridorwhatever = textboxname.text
```

The query part may be a bit different since im weiting this out of my head on a mobile phone

Comment: Thanks for your help, my tutor said that I was making things too complicated for myself and only needed to create a simple program, so I used the data set and linked the textboxes to that so that all information is displayed instead of searching and certain information being shown.
Thanks anyway!!